# Invoke the Browser using BrowserSession

Tags: blackberry

I am trying to invoke the BrowserSession to open a webpage. I usually use the following code:

```
BrowserSession browserSession = Browser.getDefaultSession();
browserSession.displayPage(link);
browserSession.showBrowser();
```

But I want now to use post method while opening the website in the same method. How can I post data into the BrowserSession?

I found the following method:

```
displayPage(String url, String referrer, HttpHeaders requestHeaders, PostData postData)
```

I've been trying it and nothing as a result ... Anyone who can help please?

Thanks

Comment: Just to be sure, are you pushing browser using browserSession.showBrowser()?

Comment: Yes I am, I put it in the code,

Comment: BrowserSession browserSession = Browser.getDefaultSession();
browserSession.displayPage(link);
browserSession.showBrowser();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you could use `BrowserSession.displayPage(String url, String referrer, HttpHeaders requestHeaders, PostData postData)` method:

```
final HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
requestHeaders.addProperty(
    HttpHeaders.HEADER_CONTENT_TYPE, 
    HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE_APPLICATION_X_WWW_FORM_URLENCODED
);

final URLEncodedPostData postData = 
    new URLEncodedPostData(URLEncodedPostData.DEFAULT_CHARSET, false);

postData.append("some_key", "some_value");
// put any key/value pairs you need to pass to the server

BrowserSession browserSession = Browser.getDefaultSession();
browserSession.displayPage(url, null, requestHeaders, postData);
browserSession.showBrowser();
```